# Synchronizing on two or more objects (Java)

Tags: java, object, synchronized, multithreading

I have code similar to following:

```
public class Cache{
 private final Object lock = new Object();
 private HashMap<Integer, TreeMap<Long, Integer>> cache = 
  new HashMap<Integer, TreeMap<Long, Integer>>();
 private AtomicLong FREESPACE = new AtomicLong(102400);

 private void putInCache(TreeMap<Long, Integer> tempMap, int fileNr){
  int length; //holds the length of data in tempMap
  synchronized(lock){
   if(checkFreeSpace(length)){
    cache.get(fileNr).putAll(tmpMap);
    FREESPACE.getAndAdd(-length);
   }
  }
 }

 private boolean checkFreeSpace(int length){      
  while(FREESPACE.get() < length && thereIsSomethingToDelete()){
   // deleteSomething returns the length of deleted data or 0 if 
   // it could not delete anything
   FREESPACE.getAndAdd(deleteSomething(length));
  }
  if(FREESPACE.get() < length) return true;
  return false;
 }
}
```

`putInCache` is called by about 139 threads a second. Can I be sure that these two methods will synchronize on both `cache` and `FREESPACE`? Also, is `checkFreeSpace()` multithread-safe i.e can I be sure that there will be only one invocation of this method at a time? Can the "multithread-safety" of this code be improved?

Comment: (There is no point using `AtomicLong` in that code.)

Answer (score 3):

To have your question answered fully, you would need to show the implementations of the thereIsSomethingToDelete() and deleteSomething() methods.

Given that checkFreeSpace is a public method (does it really need to be?), and is unsynchronized, it is possible it could be called by another thread while the synchronized block in the putInCache() method is running. This by itself might not break anything, since it appears that the checkFreeSpace method can only increase the amount of free space, not reduce it.

What would be more serious (and the code sample doesn't allow us to determine this) is if the thereIsSomethingToDelete() and deleteSomething() methods don't properly synchronize their access to the cache object, using the same Object lock as used by putInCache().

Comment: Thanks for your reply. First of all, `public` is not a big issue because these two methods are only called by another method in the same class. As for `thereIsSomethingToDelete()` and `deleteSomething()`, I do not have these method in fact. Their logic is included to `checkFreeSpace` method but it would be too messy if I would put all code here. So let's just suppose those methods are properly synchronized.

Comment: Sorry, I chose wrong methods to ask questions about. Please take a look on edited version.

Comment: So presumably putInCache() is not really private then either (otherwise how could the class actually be used). I think then that the class is threadsafe as described, since all access to mutable state can only  occur if a thread holds the lock established by the putInCache() synchronized block.

Answer (score 2):

You don't usually synchronize on the fields you want to control access to directly.
The fields that you want to synchronize access to must only be accessed from within synchronized blocks (on the same object) to be considered thread safe. You are already doing this in `putInCache()`.
Therefore, because `checkFreeSpace()` accesses shared state in an unsynchronized fashion, it is not thread safe.

Comment: what if I declare `putInCache()` as `synchronized`? Will that make both methods "safer"?

Comment: @Azimuth You need to protect access at the field level, which means all methods that access those fields need to synchronize on the same lock object. In short, you will need to add a synchronized block to the checkFreeSpace() too.